# iOS - call shouldChangeCharactersInRange programmatically

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a textfield and a delegate method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` . In this method a have a custom logic.

I want to set `textField.text` programmatically and some how call `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`

How can I do this ?

By default after setting `textField.text` method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is not called

Comment: Please check my answer and reply

Answer (score 1):

Add "UITextFieldDelegate" to your class and set:

```
textField.delegate = self;
```

### ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.textField.delegate = self;
    self.textField.text = @"Hello World";
    [self textField:self.textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.textField.text.length-1) replacementString:self.textField.text];
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    return YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: You call this method directly, he asked about the case when the method will be called by UITextField it self (the same way it does when user edits the text)